# Alpha Numeric ID's Formatting

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am generating an alpha numeric ID using the first three characters of field LastName and then an incrementing 3 digit number.  The query I am using in MSSQL 2012 is:

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName,
       UPPER(LEFT(LastName, 3)) + LEFT('000', LEN(ROW_NUMBER()
                   OVER (PARTITION BY  LEFT(LastName, 3)ORDER BY LEFT(LastName, 3)) )+1)
      +  CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  
               LEFT(LastName, 3)ORDER BY LEFT(LastName, 3))  AS NVARCHAR(1000)) AS ID
FROM @Table
```

The query works relatively well however once the numeric increments to two rather than it ending 010 it is 00010.  The same would be true once the numeric portion increments to three digits. For example, I would like an output like follows:

```
╔══════════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║ LastName ║ FirstName ║    ID    ║
╠══════════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║ Jones    ║ David     ║ JON001   ║
║ Jones    ║ David     ║ JON002   ║
║ Jones    ║ David     ║ JON003   ║
║ Jones    ║ David     ║ JON004   ║
║ Smith    ║ John      ║ SMI001   ║
║ Smith    ║ John      ║ SMI002   ║
║ Smith    ║ Robert    ║ SMI003   ║
║ Smith    ║ John      ║ SMI004   ║
║ Smith    ║ John      ║ SMI005   ║
║ Smith    ║ Robert    ║ SMI006   ║
║ Smith    ║ John      ║ SMI007   ║
║ Smith    ║ John      ║ SMI008   ║
║ Smith    ║ Robert    ║ SMI009   ║
║ Smith    ║ John      ║ SMI010   ║
║ Smith    ║ John      ║ SMI011   ║
║ Smith    ║ Robert    ║ SMI012   ║
║  ..      ║    ..     ║   ..     ║
║ Smith    ║ James     ║ SMI100   ║
╚══════════╩═══════════╩══════════╝
```

I'm not sure how to address the incrementing numerical fields.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the right instead of the left?

```
SELECT *, UPPER(LEFT(LastName, 3)) + RIGHT('000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(3)), 3)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        LastName, 
        FirstName, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(LastName, 3) ORDER BY LastName) AS ID
    FROM @table
) T
```